# Zona Horaria Javascript

Tags: javascript

Resulta que logré mostrar una imagen de acuerdo a una hora determinada. Soy de Argentina. Hice una prueba con un usuario de México y él ve una imagen distinta debido a la diferencia horaria.

¿Cómo se podría hacer para que ambos países vean la misma imagen a la hora establecida de Argentina? Por ejemplo, una imagen aparece a las 23 hs de Argentina y el usuario de México u otro país que entre a las 20 hs de México debe ver la imagen de las 23 de Argentina. Es para establecer una programación de una radio. Mostrar el artista de turno según la hora, basándome en la hora de Argentina.

Utilicé éste código pero funciona sólo para Argentina, mostrar el artista de turno, en vivo.

```js
acontinuacion adjunto el codigo que encontre

<img src="" id="imagen_cambiante" />


<script type="text/javascript">

function cambie_imagen (){
var d = new Date();
thisday=d.getDay()
var la_hora = d.getHours();

var list_images;

if(thisday == "0"){ // SI ES DOMINGO
list_images = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7 .jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","12.jpg"," 13.jpg","14.jpg","15.jpg","16.jpg","17.jpg","18.jp g","19.jpg","20.jpg","21.jpg","22.jpg","23.jpg"]

} else if (thisday == "1") { // SI ES LUNES
list_images = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7 .jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","12.jpg"," 13.jpg","14.jpg","Hola son las ","16.jpg","17.jpg","18.jp g","19.jpg","20.jpg","21.jpg","22.jpg","23.jpg"]

} else if (thisday == "2") { // SI ES MARTES
list_images = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7 .jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","12.jpg"," 13.jpg","14.jpg","15.jpg","16.jpg","17.jpg","18.jp g","19.jpg","20.jpg","21.jpg","22.jpg","23.jpg"]

} else if (thisday == "3") { // SI ES MIERCOLES
list_images = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7 .jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","12.jpg"," 13.jpg","14.jpg","15.jpg","16.jpg","17.jpg","18.jp g","19.jpg","20.jpg","21.jpg","22.jpg","23.jpg"]

} else if (thisday == "4") { // SI ES JUEVES
list_images = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7 .jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","12.jpg"," 13.jpg","14.jpg","15.jpg","16.jpg","17.jpg","18.jp g","19.jpg","20.jpg","21.jpg","22.jpg","23.jpg"]

} else if (thisday == "5") { // / SI ES VIERNES
list_images = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7 .jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","12.jpg"," 13.jpg","14.jpg","15.jpg","16.jpg","17.jpg","18.jp g","19.jpg","20.jpg","21.jpg","22.jpg","23.jpg"]

} else if (thisday == "6") { // SI ES SÁBADO
list_images = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7 .jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","12.jpg"," 13.jpg","14.jpg","15.jpg","16.jpg","17.jpg","18.jp g","19.jpg","20.jpg","21.jpg","22.jpg","23.jpg"]
}

var imagen_seleccionada = list_images[la_hora];
window.document.getElementById("imagen_cambiante") .src=imagen_seleccionada;



}
cambie_imagen();
setInterval ("cambie_imagen()", 60000 ); // Esta linea hace que cada 60 segundo cheque si cambio de hora, y asi camibar de imagen
</script>
```

Comment: Adjunto este link que podría ayudar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61518144/does-check-day-and-hour-need-to-check-timezone

Comment: Deber haber alguna manera de checkear la zona horaria, para que independientemente del país en el que ingresen vean la misma imagen, basándome en el horario argentino.

Comment: const offsetHours = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
var dd = new Date();
  dd.setHours(dd.getHours() + offsetHours);  Funcionaria algo de esto?

Answer (score 3):

En cuanto a la conjetura de [tu comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/478519/zona-horaria-javascript#comment851916_478519), claro que existe una forma de hacerlo.

**PROBLEMA**

Sin entrar mucho en detalles sobre tu implementación, el problema radica principalmente en que estás pensando, (y con toda razón), hacer un *mapeo* de cada zona horaria del mundo a la zona horaria de Argentina. Si bien esto tiene sentido, no necesitas *crear* de la nada dicho *mapeo*, cuando ya dispones de uno: [UTC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado).

Felizmente Javascript (y muchos otros lenguajes) almacenan los objetos tipo [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) en un formato UTC. Permitiendo que el mismo sea independiente de la plataforma (zona horaria) donde se visualice.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Mi propuesta es que aproveches esta característica del lenguaje, para que de esa forma puedas mostrar la imagen adecuada, independientemente de la zona horaria del cliente.

Para esto debes apoyarte en los métodos `getUTC*`, como por ejemplo[`getUTCDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay) que te devuelve el día de la semana correspondiente al horario UTC, y que será el mismo ya sea que estés en la Argentina o en la China.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código se establecen objetos `Date` con fechas diferentes, localizadas para Argentina, México, Taiwan y la zona horaria neutra GMT.

Representan el mismo instante de tiempo de forma global, es decir, cuando en México son las 20:30 horas del viernes, en Argentina serán las 22:30 también del viernes, en UTC son las 01:30 del día sábado y en Taiwan serán las 09:30 también del día sábado. Sin embargo, al solicitar el día de la semana en formato UTC, todos los objetos `Date` devuelven el mismo valor, es decir devolverán 6, ya que la fecha UTC de todas las cadenas introducidas se corresponden con el sexto día de la semana: sábado (recordemos que los días de la semana se enumeran de 0 a 6, siendo 0 el que corresponde a día Domingo, 1 para Lunes y así sucesivamente).

```js
const ar = 'August 20, 2021 22:31:30 GMT-03:00';
const mx = 'August 20, 2021 20:31:30 GMT-05:00';
const tw = 'August 21, 2021 09:31:30 GMT+08:00';
const utc = 'August 21, 2021 01:31:30 GMT';
const fechaAR = new Date(ar);
const fechaMX = new Date(mx);
const fechaTW = new Date(tw);
const fechaUTC = new Date(utc);

document.getElementById('AR-LABEL').innerText = `Argentina: ${ar}`;
document.getElementById('ES-AR').innerText = `Día de la semana UTC: ${fechaAR.getUTCDay()}`;

document.getElementById('MX-LABEL').innerText = `México: ${mx}`;
document.getElementById('ES-MX').innerText = `Día de la semana UTC: ${fechaMX.getUTCDay()}`;

document.getElementById('TW-LABEL').innerText = `Taiwan: ${tw}`;
document.getElementById('ZH-TW').innerText = `Día de la semana UTC: ${fechaTW.getUTCDay()}`;

document.getElementById('UTC-LABEL').innerText = `UTC: ${utc}`;
document.getElementById('UTC').innerText = `Día de la semana UTC: ${fechaUTC.getUTCDay()}`;
```

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.label {
  text-align: center;
}

.utc-box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.3rem auto 1rem auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label" id="AR-LABEL"></div>
  <div class="utc-box" id="ES-AR"></div>
  <div class="label" id="MX-LABEL"></div>
  <div class="utc-box" id="ES-MX"></div>
  <div class="label" id="TW-LABEL"></div>
  <div class="utc-box" id="ZH-TW"></div>
  <div class="label" id="UTC-LABEL"></div>
  <div class="utc-box" id="UTC"></div>
</div>
```

Teniendo esto en mente, lo único que debes hacer es crear tu lista de imágenes de tal forma que estén sincronizadas con la fecha y hora UTC, así, siempre mostrarás la misma imagen sin importar la zona horaria del cliente, siempre que el cliente tenga configurada correctamente su hora del sistema.

Como Argentina tiene una zona horaria establecida en `GMT-03:00` la rotación o cambio de tus imágenes debes hacerla de 3 elementos hacia la derecha (como girar una rueda en sentido horario), es decir, en vez de empezar a las 00 horas empezarás a las 21 horas:

**Visualmente:**

```js
let horasUTC = ['00-utc.jpeg', '01-utc.jpeg', ... , '23-utc.jpeg'];
//                    ^              ^                    ^
//                    |              |                    |
//                    v              v                    v
let horasARG = ['21-arg.jpeg', '22-arg.jpeg', ... , '20-arg.jpeg'];
```

De esta forma podrías tener las siguientes listas con imágenes para cada hora, de cada día de la semana:

```js
const lunes = ['mon-h21-ar.jpeg', 'mon-h22-ar.jpeg', ... , 'mon-h20-ar.jpeg'];
const martes = ['tue-h21-ar.jpeg', 'tue-h22-ar.jpeg', ... , 'tue-h20-ar.jpeg'];
```

Repetir 7 veces la misma lista, puede ser algo tedioso y rompe con con el principio [DRY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas), es por ello que en mi código usaré una estrategia para evitar repetir 7 veces la misma lista.

La siguiente implementación siempre muestra la imagen que se corresponde con la hora y el día de la Argentina, sin importar la zona horaria del cliente:

```js
const dias = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
const images = [
  '21-ar.jpeg', '22-ar.jpeg', '23-ar.jpeg',
  '00-ar.jpeg', '01-ar.jpeg', '02-ar.jpeg',
  '03-ar.jpeg', '04-ar.jpeg', '05-ar.jpeg',
  '06-ar.jpeg', '07-ar.jpeg', '08-ar.jpeg',
  '09-ar.jpeg', '10-ar.jpeg', '11-ar.jpeg',
  '12-ar.jpeg', '13-ar.jpeg', '14-ar.jpeg',
  '15-ar.jpeg', '16-ar.jpeg', '17-ar.jpeg',
  '18-ar.jpeg', '19-ar.jpeg', '20-ar.jpeg',
];

function cambiar_imagen (){
  let date = new Date(); // fecha y hora del cliente
  let dia = date.getUTCDay();  // día de la semana UTC
  let hora = date.getUTCHours();  // Hora UTC
  // con la siguiente función genero dinámicamente
  // el nombre de las imágenes según el día
  let imagenes = images.map(image => {
    return `${dias[dia]}-${image}`;
  });
  let imagen = imagenes[hora];
  document.getElementById('lbl-image').innerText = `Imagen seleccionada: ${imagen}`;
  document.getElementById('image').src = imagen;
  
}
cambiar_imagen();

setInterval (cambiar_imagen, 60000 ); // Esta linea hace que cada 60 segundo cheque si cambio de hora, y asi camibar de imagen
```

```css
#image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#lbl-image {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
  <label id="lbl-image">Imagen:</label>
  <img id="image" alt="image">
</div>
```

Actualmente yo me encuentro en la zona horaria GMT+02:00, y la hora de mi sistema marca las 08, esta es una captura del código anterior en ejecución en mi zona horaria:

[image: Captura del código en ejecución]

Como puedes observar se elije la imagen con nombre `sun-03-ar.jpeg`, que es lo que se desea, ya que siendo las 08 horas del domingo en mi zona horaria, se muestra la imagen del día domingo a las 03 horas de Argentina. (mi zona horaria le saca 5 horas de diferencia positiva a la zona de Argentina).

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

Viendo tu respuesta (que fue eliminada) veo que tienes problemas a la hora de asignar las imágenes de forma dinámica. Esto se debe a que estás concatenando el valor `mon` (abreviación que usé en mi respuesta, para indicar el día lunes) a la URL de la imagen que deseas mostrar. Entiendo que no tienes la experiencia suficiente para dar con una solución, así que me he decidido terminar de darte una ayuda.

Existen muchas formas de hacer lo que pretendes, yo te mostraré cómo lo haría yo y luego podrías intentar replicarlo.

Se me ocurre que uses un objeto en vez de una lista. Vamos a crear un objeto de imágenes con la siguiente estructura:

```js
let images = {
  mon: { ... },
  tue: { ... },
  //...
  sun: { ... }
}
```

Como se observa, tenemos un objeto llamado `images` que contiene 7 claves: `mon`, `tue`, `wed`, ... , `sun`.

A su vez, cada clave almacena un objeto, que tomará la siguiente estructura:

```
{
  ar: [
    {
      artista: <string>,
      imagen: <string>
    },
    {
      artista: <string>,
      imagen: <string>
    },
  ]
}
```

Con esta estructura ya tenemos una idea de lo que vamos a intentar. En este caso, al obtener el día de la semana y la hora, podemos buscar en nuestro objeto por día y hora y así obtener el valor del nombre del artista y su imagen. Puedes añadir más información al objeto si fuese necesario.

La estructura mostrada permite incluso poner imágenes para otras zonas horarias. No es algo que necesites, pero significa mayor libertad en caso de que la parrilla de programación varíe según sea transmitida en Argentina o en otro país. Es por ello el objeto llamado `ar` para indicar que la lista se corresponde con la zona horaria de Argentina.

Para mostrar un ejemplo sencillo, sin tener que escribir todo el objeto (toma en cuenta que son 7 días por 24 horas), usaré un objeto reducido que tenga 3 días y 2 horas diferentes en cada día (las primeras: `0` y `1`) y así se verá la forma de usar este objeto:

```js
// objeto de imagenes
let images = {
  mon: {
    ar: [
      {
        artist: 'Rafael Marin',
        image: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/52.jpg'
      },
      {
        artist: 'Esther Esteban',
        image: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/10.jpg'
      }
    ]
  },
  wed: {
    ar: [
      {
        artist: 'Sonia Fernandez',
        image: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/27.jpg'
      },
      {
        artist: 'Oscar Fernandez',
        image: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/78.jpg'
      }
    ]
  },
  sat: {
    ar: [
      {
        artist: 'Gabriel Cruz',
        image: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/91.jpg'
      },
      {
        artist: 'Angeles Pascual',
        image: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/87.jpg'
      }
    ]
  }
};

// dias de la semana
const weekDays = [
  'sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'
];

// función que cambia la imagen según la fecha y hora
function cambiar_imagen(date){
  if(!date) {
    date = new Date(); // fecha y hora del cliente
  }
  let dia = weekDays[date.getUTCDay()];  // día de la semana UTC
  let hora = date.getUTCHours();  // Hora UTC
  // basados en la hora utc obtengo la imagen adecuada
  let urlImagen = images[dia].ar[hora].image;
  let artista = images[dia].ar[hora].artist;
  document.getElementById('lbl-image').innerText = `Artista: ${artista}`;
  document.getElementById('image').src = urlImagen;
  
}

// simularemos 6 cambios cada 5 segundos
// las fechas corresponden a la zona horaria Taiwan
// se escogieron para coincidieran con la data del
// objeto creado
let fechasCambios = [
  new Date('August 21, 2021 09:31:30 GMT+08:00'), // 22hrs ARG
  new Date('August 21, 2021 08:31:30 GMT+08:00'), // 21hrs ARG
  new Date('August 23, 2021 09:31:30 GMT+08:00'), // 22hrs ARG
  new Date('August 23, 2021 08:31:30 GMT+08:00'), // 21hrs ARG
  new Date('August 18, 2021 09:31:30 GMT+08:00'), // 22hrs ARG
  new Date('August 23, 2021 08:31:30 GMT+08:00'), // 21hrs ARG
];

for(let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
  setTimeout(cambiar_imagen, 5*i*1000, fechasCambios[i]);
}
```

```css
#image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#lbl-image {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
  <label id="lbl-image">Artista:</label>
  <img id="image" alt="image" width="200">
</div>
```

Con este sencillo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, soy nuevo en esto, intentaré implementarlo paso a paso.

Comment: Una consulta, por ejemplo hay un artista distinto a las 20 hs del día sábado que a las 20 hs del domingo, y así sucede con los otros días. En este caso debería implementar el siguiente código?

Comment: const lunes = ['mon-h21-ar.jpeg', 'mon-h22-ar.jpeg', ... , 'mon-h20-ar.jpeg'];
const martes = ['tue-h21-ar.jpeg', 'tue-h22-ar.jpeg', ... , 'tue-h20-ar.jpeg'];

Comment: Hacerlo para cada uno de los días? porque no están los mismos artistas todos los días. Te agradezco de corazón por tu ayuda.

Comment: Por ejemplo la const images tiene 24 imagenes para todos los días, tendria que utilizar el código anterior para especificar por cada día los distintos dias (imagenes)? y como repercutiría en el código final : function cambiar imagen ()

Comment: Porqué sucede que me muestra bien el nombre de la imagen a mostrar pero no se carga la imagen?

Comment: Intenté pero nosé porque la imagen no se carga. La subo en formato jpg que es como las tengo editadas con photoshop. Con el método antiguo no tenía problemas con que muestre la foto, pero como le comentaba no funciona para otros países.
Su algoritmo funciona, pero aún no comprendo porque la imagen no se carga. Cargo la imagen como link desde imgbb.com. La otra duda es como se hace en el caso de tener distintos artistas en cada día. Disculpe las molestias.

Comment: @AlejandroMagnun, he editado mi respuesta para que veas un ejemplo de implementación. Espero que te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Excelente explicación, estoy viéndolo y analizándolo, yo estaba usando el código que tenia pero con las variables UTC y rotando las imágenes  const lunes = ['mon-h21-ar.jpeg', 'mon-h22-ar.jpeg', ... , 'mon-h20-ar.jpeg'];
const martes = ['tue-h21-ar.jpeg', 'tue-h22-ar.jpeg', ... , 'tue-h20-ar.jpeg'];  Parecia funcionar pero me sucedió algo raro, a las 23 de argentina del día lunes eran las 23 hs del día Martes, Cuando usted dice que comienza desde las 21 hs luego sería 22,23,0,1,2,3,4,.... todas pertenecientes al mismo día?

Comment: es como si comenzara desde atras para adelante el horario. Lo raro es que a las 0, del martes la imagen coincidia con las 0 hs de ese mismo día martes.

Comment: el problema fue a las 23 del lunes, quizas se me bugueó la caché del navegador. Luego empezó a funcionar, a las 0 hs. O quizás yo tenga algún error en la lógica. Ahora implementare su código, le agradezco mucho.

Comment: me percaté q las 21 y 21 23 del lunes corresponden al dia domingo, y asi sucesivemente

Comment: Quería agradecerte la ayuda, y la excelente explicación, funcionó, tanto tu último código como la unión de mi código antiguo y parte de tu código de la primera explicación.

Comment: Si la respuesta es válida, puedes aceptarla como tal. Haz clic en el icono de aceptar respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Disculpe no veo esa opción, pero si es válida

Comment: me surge la necesidad ahora, siguiendo la misma lógica, con el UTC, hay alguna manera de comenzar desde las 0 hs argentina en lugar de las 21 hs del día anterior? por ejemplo Lunes (0hs lunes arg.jpg,......., 23hs lunes arg.jpg)